# Angular - builds with or without animation module

Tags: angular, animation, build

**My goal is to have 2 kinds of builds for one application.**
One should import the animation module and have the animations ([@animationName] style) and one build is not importing the animation module and doesn't have animations at all.

Is it possible to do it?
The main goal is to have a smaller bundle size with the 2 builds.

Comment: JUST as an FYI the bundle size by adding Angular animation is not something you should worry about. Worry about other libraries, but angular animations is tiny

Comment: We made measurement and analyzis on the builds, and we need a build without the module.  There are parts of the world where even it's counts.